# Flat handlebar caliper brake compatibility

Tags: brakes, brake-levers

I am trying to convert my flat bar bike to drop bar. I have bought STI's but I also want to use additional brake levers(like cyclocross bikes, flat bar levers) as well.

I may be wrong but cable pull ratio of caliper brakes(which I am going to install on my bike) must be different so I think I can't use my old levers with caliper brakes. This is my first question, V brake levers can be used with calipers?(I think no)

Now I am looking for a suitable brake lever. But how can I understand if I can combine them with STI's and caliper brake? Do they have a name like "Flat bar road brake system"? I have taken a look to some bike stores on web, they only tag "v brakes" and "road brake shifters".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product you are looking for is [interrupter levers](http://www.wiggle.com/cane-creek-crosstop-brake-levers/). regular flat bar brake levers aren't designed to work in conjunction with STI levers.  The ones I linked to specifically say they are compatible with caliper/cantilever brakes.  I'm pretty sure most interrupter levers would be compatible with caliper/cantilever brakes because v-brakes don't tend to be found on bike with drop bars, which is where one would normally need interrupter levers.

Comment: Are they compatible with all? I mean if I buy this item for example, will it work for any STI's?

Comment: Well, not with hydraulic brakes. For obvious reasons.

Comment: I believe they would be compatible with any STI levers. Although you need to make sure you get the ones with the right size of clamp for your handlebar width.

Comment: So we can say pull ratios of calipers and cantilevers are fixed you say?. (A dual control lever has the same pull ratio with an interrupter lever). V brakes has their own. Don't know the working principles of hyrdolic brakes.